# Passing variables to another Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I'm trying to get variables from textboxes in one page, then pass them to be displayed in another page. Seems like I should use sessions (since that was the topic this assignment is for). The commented-out code is various methods I've tried that have not worked.

On the start page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
    }

    //This is a button link that sends to the next page, "Results"
    protected void cbtnlSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sName = "";
        int sSize = 0;
        string sTopping = "";
        decimal sPrice = 0M;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Validate();

            if (IsValid)
            {
                sName = ctbName.Text;
                sSize = Convert.ToInt32(ctbSize.Text);
                sTopping = ctbTopping.Text;
                sPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(ctbPrice.Text);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sTopping) == true)
                {
                    sTopping = "cheese";
                }

                /* DOESN'T WORK
                Session.Add(sName, sSize);
                Session.Add(sTopping, sPrice);
                Server.Transfer("Results.aspx");
                */

                /*DOESN'T WORK
                Session["pizza"] = new Pizza()
                {
                    name = sName,
                    size = sSize,
                    topping = sTopping,
                    price = sPrice
                };
                */

                //ALSO DOESN'T WORK
                Session["name"] = sName;
                Session["size"] = sSize;
                Session["topping"] = sTopping;
                Session["price"] = sPrice;
                Response.Redirect("Results.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the "Results" page that should display the variables

```
 public partial class Results : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session.Count != 0)
        {
            lblName.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
            string size = Session["size"].ToString();
            string topping = Session["topping"].ToString();
            string price = Session["price"].ToString();
            string pizzaInfo = (size + " inch pizza with " + topping + " for $" + price.ToString());
            lblPizzaInfo.Text = pizzaInfo;

            /*
            string name = Session.Keys[0];
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Session[name]);
            string topping = Session.Keys[1];
            decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(Session[topping]);

            string pizzaInfo = (size.ToString() + " inch pizza with " + topping + " for $" + price.ToString());
            lblName.Text = name;
            lblPizzaInfo.Text = pizzaInfo;
            */
        }
        lblName.Text = "Meaghan";
    }
}
```

Both pages display. The lblName.Text set at the end of the secondary page is a test to make sure the labels are visible (they are), but no information is being passed to the secondary page. That label only displays if I put it outside the if statement; nothing inside the if statement executes. I have tried reading the recommended questions and discovered I should enable "sessionState", which I did for both pages, but the program still doesn't work.

I selected EnableSessionState as True in the properties and it says EnableSessionState = "True" at the top of the aspx files. I added  to the web.config file. So I guess the session state mode is "InProc" mode?

I tried adding the Session["test"] = "Hello" into the Default page and Response.Write(Session["test"]) into the Results page. Now it throws a NullReferenceException at lblName.Text = Session["name"].ToString() [inside the if statement].

Comment: To debug, try hard-coding one of the sessions, just inside the page_load on page one.  e.g. `Session["test"] = "Hello" `  Then on page two, again in page_load, try `Response.Write(Session["test"]);`  Anything happen?

Comment: Welcome to the site Jaqueline. I removed the key words from your title - that's what the tags section is for. [What session mode](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+session+mode) have you got set up?

Comment: Hi Jacqueline, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the person who answered and to yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I tried adding the Session["test"] = "Hello" into the Default page and Response.Write(Session["test"]) into the Results page. Now it throws a NullReferenceException at lblName.Text = Session["name"].ToString() [inside the if statement]

Comment: @JacquelineConnors Have you looked at my answer below to your problem? Can you help us to help you by checking this.

Comment: @JacquelineConnors Did my answer help you out ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following in your `Web.config` at the root of your project:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />
```

Can you please confirm or not if you have this entry in your config file ?

It should be located under

```
<configuratio>
  <system.Web>
```

Further information on `sessionState`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx